# How to fix error and install xmgrace smoothly?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, homebrew, xmgrace

I tried to install xmgrace via brew with the command `brew install grace`, but then following error occurs:

```
Error: No available formula for grace 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
homebrew/x11/grace
```

I operate in the bash shell on a Mac OSX Yosemite (V10.10.2).

**How can I fix the error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Install Xcode 
(search the Apple app store and install from there, then at the command prompt type: xcode-select --install)
Second: install open motif 
(at the terminal prompt, type: sudo port install openmotif)
Third: Install xmgrace
(at the terminal prompt, type: sudo port install grace)
Fourth: Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to install MacPorts though.

Answer (score 0):

At some point since early 2015 now you have to do:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/x11
$ brew install grace
```

Full set of instructions to [install xmgrace on OSX](http://nokyotsu.com/qscripts/2011/05/installing-xmgrace-on-snow-lepoard.html).